# Specified type is not registered on the target server EF Core for spatial point bulk insert

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-extensions

I am using .NET Core MVC, Entity Framework Core, Entity Framework Extensions. I am trying to insert bulk addresspoint in EF Core through `BulkInsertAsync` method, but I am getting an error

> Specified type is not registered on the target server

As Entity Framework Core has nettopologysuite for spatial data type. The `BulkInsert` method of Entity Framework Extension works fine in Entity Framework 6, but not in Entity Framework Core.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

```
var geometryFactory = NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326);
var newBreadcrumbs = (from b in addressPoints
                      select new BreadCrumb
                                 {
                                     CarrierId = carrierID,
                                     Point = geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(b.Longitude, b.Latitude)),
                                     Speed = b.Speed.GetValueOrDefault() * (Decimal)2.237,
                                     Direction = b.Direction,
                                     CapturedFrom = b.CapturedFrom,
                                     CapturedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                     Accuracy = (Decimal)b.Accuracy,
                                     IsDisconnect = b.IsDisconnect,
                                     CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                     IsActive = true,
                                     CreatedBy = 0,
                                     ModifiedBy = 0,
                                     ModifiedOn = null
                                 }).ToList();

// this line of code causes the error
await dbCOntext.BulkInsertAsync(newBreadcrumbs);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please can you provide some sample code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @simon_dmorias thanks for your suggestion and support.Please see I just put code here

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported in the project GitHub: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/issues/209

Starting from v2.2.7, EF Extensions now support spatial type through the `nettopologysuite` packages.